# Format a list of lists of dataframes

Tags: r, list, purrr

I am trying to learn `purr` and so I look for solutions related to it.
Suppose I have a list with 3 elements, whose elements are themselves lists of dataframes:

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = c('alfa', 'beta', 'omega'), b = rnorm(3,0,1), c = NA)
a2 <- data.frame(a = c('lambda', 'delta', 'epsilon'), b = rnorm(3,0, 1), c = NA)
b1 <- data.frame(a = c('lambda', 'delta', 'alfa'), b = rnorm(3, 1, 1), c = 1)
b2 <- data.frame(a = c('beta', 'delta', 'epsilon'), b = rnorm(3, 1, 2), c = c(0, 1, NA))

a <- list(a1, a2)
b <- list(b1, b2)

L <- list(a,b)
```

How can I format L using `map*_` in such a way that all first columns all converted to character (I do not need to know a general case in which any column could have factors) and also such that `NA`s are removed?

Since there is more than one level of nesting, I don't know how to call functions without unnesting anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` option could be:

```
map_depth(.x = L, 2, ~ .x %>%
           mutate_at(1, as.character) %>%
           na.omit())

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] a b c
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[1]][[2]]
[1] a b c
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
       a         b c
1 lambda 0.6691767 1
2  delta 1.5106571 1
3   alfa 1.8121246 1

[[2]][[2]]
      a          b c
1  beta -0.4429880 0
2 delta -0.7539317 1
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer, but weirdly ```R``` tells me that there is no such function

Comment: Perhaps you are using an older version of `purrr`. Please try to update to the newest one :)

Comment: Supposing I want instead to change all columns but the first from character to numeric. I've adapted the solution to L <-  map_depth(.x = L, 2, ~ .x %>%
            mutate_at(-c(1), as.numeric) %>%
            na.omit())

Why is this not working? There are NA's introduced everywhere

Comment: If you are trying to convert a character vector to a numeric one, then it won't work if does not contain numbers that can be converted. Otherwise, `map_depth(.x = L, 2, ~ .x %>%
           mutate_at(-1, as.numeric) %>%
           na.omit())` should work and is working on your sample data.

Comment: Ok, now I understood my problem. My numbers are formated as such that ```print(head(L$a$a1)) = "150,27" "0,00"   "0,00"   "0,00"   "0,00"   "0,00"```.

Maybe those cannot be converted properly

Comment: You can specify that your decimal is `,` when importing your data into `R`. Then, they will be recognized as numbers. Or you do `as.numeric(sub(",", ".", x))`.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness and for future users who may prefer to stick with `base` for whatever reason, here is a `base` solution that assumes all data frames will have the same names:

```
    lapply(L,lapply,function(x) na.omit(within(x,
                                   { a <-as.character(a)})))
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] a b c
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[1]][[2]]
[1] a b c
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
       a          b c
1 lambda -0.7389969 1
2  delta  0.9791327 1
3   alfa  1.4097145 1

[[2]][[2]]
      a          b c
1  beta -0.3176996 0
2 delta  2.8242954 1
```

Alternatively, if the names differ across dataframes,

```
 lapply(L,lapply,function(x) na.omit(replace(x,1,as.character(x[,1]))))
```

**NOTE**: This is probably less flexible than the `purrr` solution since you have no control over the indexing level(i.e for `purrr` you can decide to go up to a certain depth) There might be a way with `rapply` or `lapply` itself but  I'm not aware of one.

Structure of the result:

```
   List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    0 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ a: chr(0) 
  .. ..$ b: num(0) 
  .. ..$ c: logi(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Named int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
  ..$ :'data.frame':    0 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ a: chr(0) 
  .. ..$ b: num(0) 
  .. ..$ c: logi(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Named int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ a: chr [1:3] "lambda" "delta" "alfa"
  .. ..$ b: num [1:3] -0.739 0.979 1.41
  .. ..$ c: num [1:3] 1 1 1
  ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ a: chr [1:2] "beta" "delta"
  .. ..$ b: num [1:2] -0.318 2.824
  .. ..$ c: num [1:2] 0 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Named int 3
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "3"
```